# How to add confirmation dialog in the beforeSubmit event using struts2-jquery sj:a

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using `struts2-jquery plugin` in my application, i'm using its `sj:a` component to submit forms. Everything works fine until a requirement came up that I've to display a confirmation dialog before submission of the form. I'm using `jquery.alert plugin` for displaying confirmation dialog.
The problem is that in this `jconfirm` dialog is not blocking, the `jconfirm` message is displayed but the event continues its execution. Any ideas on how to stop execution of `beforesubmit` event until user clicks the confirmation dialog?

I'm using following code

```
    var result = false;
    if(flag == 'true') {
        jConfirm("Message", "Note", function(choice) {
            if(choice) {
                submitFlag = true;
                $.publish('beforeSaveMilestoneSubmit');
            } 
        });

    } else {
        submitFlag = true;
        $.publish('beforeSaveMilestoneSubmit');
    }
```

Comment: Please share if you already had a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution here for this problem. This solution is a little hacky, but it worked very well for me. The solution is:

```
<sj:a formIds="form1"  
      id="delete_link"
      targets="itemlist" 
      onBeforeTopics="before" 
      href="yourhref">Delete Item</sj:a>

<!--Duplicate the anchor, but hide it and set listenTopcs-->  

<sj:a formIds="form1"  
     id="delete_link_hidden"
     targets="itemlist" 
     listenTopics="confirmed" 
     href="yourhref" 
     style="display:none;">Delete Item</sj:a>
```

Java Script here:

```
$.subscribe('before',function(event,data){  
event.originalEvent.options.submit=false;  
if(jConfirm("Message", "Note", function(choice))  
    $.publish('confirmed');  
});
```

Comment: i have fixed the issue using some what same approach,using a fake anchor to use for verification and then trigger the click of original sj:a for actual functionality